# converting pdf to png or jpg with imagemagick: png has antialiasing, jpg does not?

Tags: pdf, image-processing, imagemagick, png, antialiasing

I'm trying to get imagemagick to convert a .pdf to .jpg at high resolution *with antialiasing*.

`convert -density 300 test.pdf test.jpg` gives: (zoomed 200% to show the effect)
[image]

However `convert -density 300 test.pdf test.png` (note .png output instead of .jpg) gives:
[image]

Actually the png is transparent and I'd need it flattened on white, but I'm mainly concerned about the difference in anti-aliasing.

I could probably work around this by converting to png first and then to jpg, or converting with to a much higher density and resizing that down (e.g. `-density 1200 -resize 25%`) thus subsampling, which is effectively antialiasing.

But I'm wondering why this happens in the first place. How come the jpg is not anti-aliased while the png is, and is there a way to directly enable anti-aliasing for the jpg as well? (I tried `-antialias` but that didn't work)

Comment: You were on the right track.  Try flattening the image before writing to JPG as well.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson, is it possible to flatten every PDF page and then save output to different JPEGs instead of a single one?

Comment: Try something like convert in.pdf page%04.png; mogrify -flatten page*.jpg